# How to change to dualstack subnet and update a VM Instance stacktype - Google cloud - IPv6 support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance on google cloud with IPv4.

I want to create a letsencrypt certificate for my nginx and the validation error seems to suggest that ipv6 is required

When attempted  to edit network interface and help takes me to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address

> "If you are changing the stack type to dual-stack, the VM must be
> connected to a dual-stack subnet. If you need to change which subnet
> the VM is connected to, ***stop the VM and change the subnet***. After
> the subnet is updated, you can change the VM's IP stack type."

But not sure of the steps on how to change subnet

Can I get help to create subnet and enable ipv6 i.e. dual stack

[image]

Comment: Let's Encrypt does not require IPv6. If you have both IPv4 and IPv6 DNS resource records, Let's Encrypt will prefer IPv6 but will fall back to IPv4. Do not use screenshots. Copy and Paste the text into your question with a problem description. FYI your screenshot is unusable.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I am working on one and only one problem. I am following this article - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

Skipped step 3, as I read somewhere that ufw if made active will be a problem 

Error: "
Failed authorization procedure. www.p****e.co.uk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: *e.co.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/d0#####CC7RL-MDLU7#####LR6X7-2##-8: 404" . command run from compute engine with firewall ports 80 and 8443 open. Domain

Comment: the question is about how to create subnet for ipv6 and enable. Hence the screenshot to show IP stack type v4 and v6 is disabled. Lets encrypt may fallback. as the question is not from the perspective of how to get certbot command work, I did not put the log. hope this explains the reasoning behind adding the screenshot